# rename top 10 latest file according to their names

Tags: ls

I have some .xls files in a defined directory (say in /A/B).
I want to rename top 10 latest files and append "-bkp" in their names.

I tried, not working

```
ls -lt *.xls | head -1 | awk '{print "mv " $9 " "$9-bkp}' | sh
```

I tried find and -exec but how do we get top l0 latest modified files

Answer (score 0):

The reason your script is failing is that `$9-bkp` is treated as an expression: the `-bkp` should also be quoted, so the line should be:

```
ls -lt *.xls | head -10 | awk '{print "mv " $9 " "$9"-bkp"}' | sh
```

However, this is needlessly complicated: you are list a lot of file attributes, then use `awk` to extract the name. Also, you don't need to launch a subshell to execute the generated commands. Furthermore, the command above will not work if there are spaces in a file name.

The following addresses all of these points:

```
ls -t *.xls | head -10 | while read; do mv "$REPLY" "$REPLY-bkp"; done
```

In this case, `ls -t` lists only the file names, one per line; `read` copies each full line into `REPLY`, including all spaces, whether embedded, leading, or trailing; and the `mv` command is run for each line.

Note that the more common `read name` will copy a line into `name`, but without leading and trailing spaces.